# JavaDB/Derby Error 08006

Tags: java, database, derby, javadb

In the article [Using Java DB in Desktop Applications](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/javadb/) the [Address Book demo](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/javadb/AddressBookCode.zip) have a method disconnect which have a try-catch block that catch and ignores the exception. If you add a printStackTrace you can see that the exception always occur.

What's wrong here? The JavaDB should not throw this exception, or they should fix something in the example program?

Comment: Could you paste the exception you're getting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Shutdown commands always raise SQLExceptions.](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.5/devguide/tdevdvlp20349.html) So nothing's wrong. That's just the way Derby works.